# Video not playing in HTML <video> tag

Tags: html, firefox, video

My video plays in browser chromium or firefox when I provide the link as follows:

http://localhost/vcenew/clients_hub/kiran_927/kiran2/outputs/vid1007.mp4

But the same video does not play in  tag.

Here is the code:

```
<video width="620" height="600" controls="">vid1007.mp4
    <source src="/var/www/html/vcenew/clients_hub/kiran_927/kiran2/outputs/vid1007.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

I did read compatibilty articles which says that firefox and chromium supports mp4 partially. But I did try ogg format too which is supported by  firefox and chromium both and it is not working.

Here is the link which I read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

please help...

Comment: I don't think the browser is going to be able to get to your server root (which is what you have provided as your source). What happens if you try to use the url exactly how it appears in the browser? ie. with the `http://localhost/` at the start.. in the `src` attribute?

Comment: I tried that too but did not work.I think the reason is mp4 is not supported by the browser.but how can I overcome it?

Comment: I really don't think it's a case of mp4 not being support.. it's a very standard video filetype. If you're absolutely certain that it will not work by providing a standard URL, then maybe you should look at using a plugin, or a way of converting your video into multiple filetypes, and then providing all of them, for the browser to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I recommend hosting the video file in several formats: H.264, OGG and WebM to reassure that it plays well in all modern browsers. If you still have issues with playback check video converters like Freemake Video Converter or HandBreak.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will be able to play most of the video if its extension is .mp4 and the codec used is h264 in the video tag of Html5 .